# I edited an answer, adding what seems to me was necessary information, but got rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, specific-edit, reject-reasons

TLDR: [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/28338368) was rejected with "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

I disagree with this reasoning. I added details to a very short answer, and my details didn't deviate from the intent of the person posting the answer, as I see it.

[image]

More details:

Yesterday I was searching for an answer about applying formula to the entire column in a spreadsheet.

I found this question: [Apply formula to the entire column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941209/apply-formula-to-the-entire-column)

The question specifically asks: *"Is there a formula I could use to solve this problem?"*, which is exactly what I was wondering, too.

This answer shows how to create an `arayformula` using three keys. The answer apparently assumes windows, while I'm using a Mac, so the three-key combination didn't work for me. But with a little experimenting, I figured out the correct key combination for Mac.

I edited the answer to include the key combination for Mac

And I added a short explanation of what happens when you press that three-key combination.

My edit was rejected with the comment: "This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner."

This reject doesn't make sense to me.

- I added the three-key combination for Mac. Was the original intent supposed to be for Windows only?
- I added the explanation of what the three-key combination does, and that you need to press `enter` afterwards (because I saw in the comments that some people were confused). Was the original intent supposed to be confusing?
- I added a paragraph about what to do if you want to start in a different row, instead of row 1 -- possibly that was too drastic?

> If your sheet contains header row(s), and you want to apply formula
> from (for example) row 5 on, you would use =text(A5:A,"00000")
> instead.

- And finally, I added the note that the cell below need to be empty, otherwise the solution from this answer wouldn't work.

---

UPDATE:

I see that many people find the addition of Mac key combination irrelevant, which honestly surprises me.

In many cases it is true that the Windows `Ctrl+<something>` is usually `Command+<something>` on Mac, but that is **not** always true.

Comment: That should be [Windows](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=windows) and [Mac](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=macintosh) (not "windows" and "MAC").

Comment: @PeterMortensen Good point. Could be fixed with further editing.

Answer (score 17):

The simplest reason I'd personally reject that edit, is:

You **quintupled** the length of that answer. If your edit requires that you add that much to an answer, it should probably be a standalone answer.

To answer your specific points:

- The mac shortcut is pretty redundant. As far as I can tell, it's pretty common knowledge that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> means <kbd>Cmd</kbd> when you're on a mac. That doesn't really add much to the answer.
- The line that you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply the change is just as redundant...
- The "other row" line is unrelated to the question.
- The thing about the empty line is just something one person apparently fiddled with. We don't need to spoonfeed solutions that cover every single corner case...

In the end, the edit adds a lot of fluff to an otherwise short and simple answer.

Comment: It's very easy to *quintuple* such a short answer.

Comment: Just because it's easy, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: It also seems like a "reply", we are not a forum, where other users can quote other user's answers and reply to them.  **I would reject the edit for the simple fact it added a "thanks @username" which is noise.**

Comment: I thought I'm supposed to give credit if I use information from someone's comment.

Comment: `As far as I can tell, it's pretty common knowledge that Ctrl means Cmd when you're on a Mac` -- most of the time, but __not__ *always*. Macs have `Ctrl` key as well. Example: in PyCharm, "find in files" is `ctrl-shift-F` whether Mac or Windows.

Comment: @SecurityHound Then, why do we have @ replies in comments? eternal_student simply just added a few extra details and credited one user which is required by the CC-BY-SA license I think.

Comment: You can’t equate comments to answers, @10Rep.

Comment: But you still need to give credit to comments in answers, @Cerbrus. Regardless of whether it is a comment or answer. I think, Improve edit or Reject and Edit is correct.

Comment: Regarding the size of my edits -- from *"How do I write a good answer?"* : "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do **try to mention** any **limitations**, **assumptions** or simplifications in your answer. **Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better**."

Comment: @eternal_student: That's advice for _writing_ an answer. You ___edit___ added a lot to an ___existing___ answer... One that's 6 years old already. Edits should fix existing problems in answers. They shouldn't add that much new stuff to them.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Obviously you have been around for way longer than me, and you have a better idea of what the community needs. I realize I am just one of the users, and the rules of the site are based on general consensus. While you have not convinced me that my edits are bad, I think I understand your rationale.  I was **not** trying to get the rejection reversed; just understand.  I will keep your advice in mind for future edits.

Answer (score 4):

To make [Cerbrus' answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405327/1079354) a bit more laconic:

An edit to a post should not cause whole paragraphs to *appear*.

Comment: For an answer of this length that statement is broadly correct, but there are answers on this site that are almost encyclopaedic in detail, and for such the addition of a paragraph would be a relatively minor edit.

Comment: I agree with @IanKemp -- such a general rule as in "don't quintuple" or "don't add a whole paragraph" seems overly simplistic.

Answer (score 3):

While I don't disagree with the **intent** of your edit, the **implementation** leaves something to be desired. I would likely have selected to "Reject and Edit" your change, and modified it to the following:

> What you need is an [array formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275), which is applied to all cells in a column. Enter the following in B1:
>
> `=text(A1:A,"00000")`
>
> and **do not hit Enter** - instead press the key combination `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to convert that formula to an array formula, *then* hit `Enter` again to apply the formula.
>
> Note that the cells below the one where you are entering the formula **must be empty** (thanks @LOAS).

The above is quite a bit longer than the current short-and-sweet answer, but not overly so (IMO - YMMV) and includes some pertinent information (array formula and a reference link for the same, plus the potential sticking point re empty cells).

It also omits the "I think you are in luck. Please..." fluff, as well as the completely irrelevant Mac shortcut keys. The bit about header rows is useful but isn't an answer to the question asked, hence I excluded it too.

Comment: The fluff about the luck was there and I didn't go out of my way to remove it.

Comment: I don't understand why so many people say that the Mac shortcuts are irrelevant. I'm new to Mac, and I'm still learning. And whenever I look up some information that is supposed to be OS-independent, I prefer to see how it works on Mac.